# Dirac delta function like a "function" of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Let $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset \mathcal{S}^*$ be the Schwartz space, the Hilbert space and the space of tempered distributions respectively. Consider an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of operators with continuous spectrum. We see delta function as the element of $\mathcal{S}^*$, i.e. continuous (in kernal topology with seminorms $f \mapsto \|Af\|, A\in \mathcal{A}, f\in \mathcal{H}$) linear functional on $\mathcal{S}$.

Question: how can we correctly define an action of $\delta(A-\vec{x}), A\in \mathcal{A}, \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ on $f\in \mathcal{H}\,?$

For example, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199757/can-operators-be-argument-of-dirac-delta-function) we have the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by operators $X \colon f(\vec{x})\mapsto \vec{x} f(\vec{x})$ and $P \colon f(\vec{x})\mapsto \partial_\vec{x} f(\vec{x})$ with $[X,P]=iI$. Emilio Pisanty tell that functions of the position operator should work $⟨x|F(X)=F(\vec{x})⟨x|$ but I don't understand how it work with delta function.

Also we can find ([here](https://phy.ntnu.edu.tw/~changmc/Teach/SM/ch01.pdf) on p.13 formula (74)) the Fourier transform of operator $\rho(\vec{x})=\delta(X-\vec{x})$: $$\rho(\vec{k})=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R^n}} e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}\rho(\vec{x})\,d\vec{x}=e^{-i\vec{k}X}.$$

I will be very grateful for any remarks and comments.

Comment: What is $A-\vec{x}$? and then what is $\delta(A-\vec{x})$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, $(A-\vec{x})f(\vec{x})=Af-\vec{x}f$ and I don't understand what is $\delta(A-\vec{x})$, I think that it's wrong form of something correct. By anology we have $\int f(\vec{x})\delta(A-\vec{x})\, d\vec{x}=f(A),$ but it looks senseless. Is it correct: $\delta(A-\vec{x})=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{i(A-\vec{x})\cdot \vec{y}}\,d\vec{y} \, ?$

Comment: I don't know how to make sense of an operator minus a vector.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, and how to make sense of $\delta(A), A\in \mathcal{A} \,?$

Comment: Maybe we can write formal expansion and put to it an operator: $$\delta(A-x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ik(A-x)}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ik(-x)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ikA)^n}{n!} \, ?$$

Comment: Than we have $\left<x|\delta(X-x_0)|\psi \right>=\left<x|\delta(x-x_0)|\psi 
 \right>=\delta(x-x_0)\left<x|\psi \right>$

Comment: Good luck with answers you might be getting in this SE. In the PSE, you understand that  functions of operators are understood as some type of formal consistent Taylor expansion, and so the Fourier representation of the δ function is as well-defined as the exponential of an operator times *i*, no?